# org.apache import cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, buildpath

I know that this error has been queried many times. I've read these posts, but I still cannot get this to work. I have this error:

`The import org.apache cannot be resolved`

You can see here that I have included the .jar file in my build path. I got this jar file [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/download_collections.cgi) and I am using Java 7.

I've also cleaned the project and restarted Eclipse. Can anyone suggest what I should try next? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: if you expand the gray arrow at the left of the jar icon, can you see there the package you need?

Comment: Never mind. It seems that downloading the .jar doesn't work. I wound up downloading a zip from GitHub and building it via Maven.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Eclipse -> Preferences search for target platform, press Restore Defaults, press Apply and then press Reload.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a Target Platform option, nor do I have a Plug-in Development option. Not even when I search for them.

Comment: You don't have it because you are looking in your project's properties, not in the Eclipse Preferences like I've told.